# Unable to vote on close votes due to incorrect floating box sizing problem

Tags: bug, design, moderation

There is a small bug in that trying to cast a close vote pushes the hovering pop-up off the screen. This is when doing [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/) and scrolling down the page. This is a recent macOS with a recent Chrome. Any workaround?

[image: Screenshot with buttons off end of screen]

Comment: Switch to another browser for the next several weeks until the next version of Chrome lands and pray that it's gone away by then. (It usually does.)

Comment: how much you wanna bet the user in question down-voted you?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on macOS 10.13.5 (latest) and Chrome 67.0.3396.87 (latest), unless I reduce my window size to less than 1100 pixels width, but that's not the case in your screenshot, so please update your softwares.

Comment: @snb Which user? pydev? I'd be prepared to bet a lot that they didn't. As they don't have sufficient rep to downvote anybody.

Answer (score -3):

Workaround is to update your softwares, because as stated in my comment on Jun 23 '18:

> I cannot reproduce it on macOS 10.13.5 (latest) and Chrome 67.0.3396.87 (latest), unless I reduce my window size to less than 1100 pixels width, but that's not the case in your screenshot

Comment: No.  Probably related to using the OSX zoom fighting with a flexbox.  "It worked on my machine" is not exactly the height of troubleshooting.  Meh, it doesn't bother me; I just stopped voting.

Comment: @CharlesMerriam I can't reproduce with zoom either.