# The triage review bar with the action buttons is clipped

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, user-interface

The triage review bar extends past the edge of my browser window. This is fine (if annoying) when I’m at the top of the page as I can horizontally scroll. But when I scroll down (say, to read the question) the bar’s `x` position is locked to the viewport.

Therefore if I want to skip a question I have to scroll back to the top of the page and then scroll horizontally.

I can however remove the need for horizontal scrolling by increasing the width of my browser.

[image: Clipped review bar]

---

This differs from an [earlier question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369929/unable-to-vote-on-close-votes-due-to-incorrect-floating-box-sizing-problem) in that it does depend on my browsers width. Also my software is fully updated so the given answer does not apply.

---

## Metrics

If this behaviour occurs depends on the left navigation visibility and the width of the browser window. Enabling or disabling responsiveness had no noticeable effect.

Without the left navigation:

- **1084px** all buttons are fully visible.
- **1117px** there is no longer a horizontal scrollbar

With the left navigation:

- **1246px** all buttons are fully visible
- **1281px** there is no longer a horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 62.0 (64bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in chrome?

Comment: I don't have Chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to vote on close votes due to incorrect floating box sizing problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369929/unable-to-vote-on-close-votes-due-to-incorrect-floating-box-sizing-problem)

Comment: @Xuf That does seem to be a similar bug but the cause would appear to be different. E,g, if I make my browser really wide this issue goes away. I'd also note that Cœur's answer does not apply here.

Comment: No Repro on Firefox 62.0 on Windows 7. What is your monitor resolution?

Comment: @TylerH 1440x900, I'm not sure how that is relevant though?

Comment: @ChrisD Well if you have a monitor or browser window size incapable of displaying the whole page it is very relevant. And sorry, I meant what is your browser viewport resolution (where it starts getting cut off), not monitor resolution.

Comment: @TylerH Ah, that would be 1000x700

Comment: I updated the question with some metrics.

Comment: @ChrisD Hmm, yeah, it may be by design if you are at 1000x700. At 1000w with the sidebar enabled I can only see out to the E in the "Requires Editing" button.

Comment: @TylerH Sure the extreme width may be by design but it surely isn't on purpose that horizontal scrolling is broken vertically scrolling down the page.