# Review layout bug pushes action buttons off screen

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

When my browser window is at a comfortable (for me) width, approximately 1000-1200 pixels on my current work-issued monitor, there is a layout issue in the review pages. After scrolling down into the content, the review action buttons (e.g. *I'm Done*, *Skip*) are pushed off-screen to the right making them inaccessible.

In some instances, it makes the *No Action Needed* button the only one visible, visually implying that it's the only possible action and making it less likely that a reviewer chooses one of the other actions, when appropriate.

The following screenshot is from a user agent roughly 1100px wide.  I need to horizontally scroll quite a bit to the right to fit the entire review area in the window (it won't reflow to a smaller width).  In many areas, SO's design seems to assume that the client window area is at least 1280px.  While the horizontal scrolling is annoying, everything I need in order to perform the review is usable when *vertically* scrolled to the very top of the page.

[image: StackOverflow review page in a browser, scrolled 100% right at top of page]

However, scroll down *just a bit* and the page "responsively" reflows -- but two out of the three buttons are pushed off the screen.  The horizontal scrollbar is still 100% right, so the buttons are simply inaccessible.  These screenshots are from the First Posts review queue, but the issue is present on other review queues, too.

[image: same image as above, but scrolled down the page slightly, which cuts off two of three action buttons on the right margin]

It didn't turn up in my search before posting, but the *Related* sidebar revealed a somewhat similar complaint in: [The triage review bar with the action buttons is clipped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374153/2390644).

Comment: Well they aren't circles, but at least they're red and freehand.  +1.

Comment: Can confirm on FF Windows (which it looks like you're using as well).  You just have to make the window sufficiently small and scroll down.

Comment: This looks like JavaScript attempting to do the job of CSS.

Comment: Is the blur on the gravatar a meta joke about paper bags?

Comment: @Braiam a metal joke perhaps, but it's not a paper bag