# Review buttons end up off the right side of the browser at scale 120%

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

When I am at the top of the page it is OK:

[image: All buttons for reviewing Closed questions are fully visible. The box containing them is aligned to the left.]

But when I scroll down, then the element moves off of the screen despite there being space on the left side:

[image: The box containing the buttons has shifted to the right. The last button, Skip, is almost entirely off the page.]

I'm using Firefox version 79.0.

At 100% it also off of the screen (size: 800x600).

[image: None of the review buttons are visible and some of the question text is also cut off.]

PS: At 100% the font is too small. I can not read the site =(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Review layout bug pushes action buttons off screen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374683/review-layout-bug-pushes-action-buttons-off-screen)

Comment: @lvar: Notice, that in my example I use scale 120%. That example does not.

Comment: It would surprise me if that was a different bug, but who knows. I'll retract my close vote. That being said, I can't reproduce the issue. What browser/version are you using?

Comment: @lvar: FF v79.0

Comment: scaling is still not confirmed to be supported. If the glitch doesn't happen at 100% this is [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: They’re currently reworking the review UI _anyway_.

Comment: @rene: At 100%  it also out of screen

Comment: @EugenKonkov then just remove the 120% zoom issues from the post entirely. Anything other than the default 100% is unsupported

Comment: Does SO support FF 79? ... [I guess so, since 78 ESR is supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/194720).

Comment: Re *"When I on top it is OK"*: Do you mean *"When I **am** on top it is OK"*? (missing word?)

Comment: Re *"element out of"*: Do you mean *"element **goes** out of"*? (missing word?)

Comment: Re *"also out of"*: Do you mean *"also **goes** out of"*? (missing word?)

Comment: What is *"positionint"*? Is it literal?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I believe the last one is supposed to be "positioning" but the OP overshot the "g".

Comment: Your browser window does not appear to be maximized in the last screenshot. Can you confirm that you still have this problem even when the window is full screen?

Comment: @BSMP: 800x600. This is my monitor resolution. I provide this info already ;-)

Comment: I wasn’t asking for your resolution, I was asking if the browser window is full screen. We can see some kind of text document on the right hand side of your screenshot behind the browser, which shouldn’t be possible if it’s full screen.